# How to save data before widget got disposed

Tags: flutter, dispose, inherited-widget

I'm trying to save a value back to InheritedWidget before the widget is disposed of,

```
void disposed() {
  AppInheritedWidget.of(context).update(value);
  super.disposed();
}
```

but got the following error:

> [image]

Is there a good way to save value before the widget got destroyed?

I do see that the error message suggest keeping a reference during didChangeDependencies(), but that's like the native mobile way of doing things. Having an instance variable around instead of the flutter way to get the `"AppInheritedWidget.of(context)"` during build(), not ideal.

Any suggestion?